# Convert pandas Series with categories as values to DataFrame mask

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a very simple problem which I'm unsure how to solve with a few simple calls. I have the following Series:

```
In [3]: d = pd.Series(data=['A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'D', 'B'], index=range(7))

In [4]: d
Out[4]: 
0    A
1    A
2    B
3    C
4    D
5    D
6    B
dtype: object
```

and I'd like to transform the above into:

```
In [5]: pd.DataFrame({'A':[1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 'B': [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1], 'C':[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0], 'D':[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0]})
Out[5]: 
   A  B  C  D
0  1  0  0  0
1  1  0  0  0
2  0  1  0  0
3  0  0  1  0
4  0  0  0  1
5  0  0  0  1
6  0  1  0  0
```

In words, have a Series with duplicate values. I want to create a DataFrame with same index as the Series and columns being the unique set of values of the series. I then want to populate each column putting 1s at each index where the column name existed in the Series and 0 elsewhere. Not sure how to do it in a simple way.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/38701573/2137255 and couple of others.

Comment: Unfortunately you are right, all simple questions are dupes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`pd.get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html):

```
In [419]: pd.get_dummies(d).astype(int)
Out[419]: 
   A  B  C  D
0  1  0  0  0
1  1  0  0  0
2  0  1  0  0
3  0  0  1  0
4  0  0  0  1
5  0  0  0  1
6  0  1  0  0
```

The (slightly) shorter version in the other answers work too.

Answer (score 3):

we can use [Series.str.get_dummies](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html):

```
In [308]: d.str.get_dummies()
Out[308]:
   A  B  C  D
0  1  0  0  0
1  1  0  0  0
2  0  1  0  0
3  0  0  1  0
4  0  0  0  1
5  0  0  0  1
6  0  1  0  0
```

alternatively we can use [sklearn.preprocessing.LabelBinarizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelBinarizer.html):

```
In [321]: from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelBinarizer

In [322]: lb = LabelBinarizer()

In [323]: pd.DataFrame(lb.fit_transform(d), columns=lb.classes_, index=d.index)
Out[323]:
   A  B  C  D
0  1  0  0  0
1  1  0  0  0
2  0  1  0  0
3  0  0  1  0
4  0  0  0  1
5  0  0  0  1
6  0  1  0  0
```